# Interpolation error with gsl_interp_linear

Tags: c++, gsl

I need to interpolate a modified Bessel function and I use for that the function `gsl_spline_eval()`. I get a 'gsl: interp.c:145: ERROR: interpolation error' with the following code:

```cpp
 #define MAXPOINTS 10000 
 int main()
{
    double nu;
    gsl_function F;
    F.function = &sync;
    F.params =0;
    size_t size;    
    double table[2][MAXPOINTS];
    size = read_table(table[0],table[1]);   
    gsl_interp_accel *acc      =      gsl_interp_accel_alloc ();
    gsl_spline *spline         =      gsl_spline_alloc   (gsl_interp_linear, 5401); 
    gsl_spline_init(spline,table[0],table[1],size);
    cout <<" nu:   "<< nu<< "  GSL_FN_EVAL(&F,nu):   "<<nu*GSL_FN_EVAL(&F,nu)<<endl;

 return 0;
}
```

Where `sync()` returns the integral of the function `sync_kern()` using the gsl function `gsl_integration_qag()`. The function `read_table()` is defined as follow:

```cpp
size_t read_table(double *xa, double *ya)
{
    size_t datapoints;
    datapoints = 5401;
    double x[] = {
        1.388794e-11,
        1.395756e-11,
        ...       };
    double y[] = {
        5.166810e-04,
        5.175428e-04,
        ...
                 };
    int i = 0;
    while(i<datapoints){ 
        xa[i]=log(x[i]);
        ya[i]=log(y[i]);
        i++;
        }

return datapoints;  
}
```

The function `sync_kern()` is the following:

```cpp
double sync_kern(double gamma, void *params)
{
    struct func_params *part= (struct func_params *)params;
    double result;
    double P,x, nuc, nu_0;
    double nu = *(double *)params;                
    gamma = exp(gamma);
    nu_0    =   (3*E_COULOMB*B*sqrt(2/3.0))/(4.0*M_PI*M*C);
    nuc     =   nu_0*sq(gamma);     
    x   =   nu/nuc;

    gsl_interp_accel *acc      =      gsl_interp_accel_alloc ();
    gsl_spline *spline     =      gsl_spline_alloc (gsl_interp_linear, 5401);


     /* double table[2][MAXPOINTS];
    size = read_table(table[0],table[1]);   
    gsl_interp_accel *acc      =      gsl_interp_accel_alloc ();
        gsl_spline *spline    =      gsl_spline_alloc (gsl_interp_interp, 5401);        
    gsl_spline_init(spline,table[0],table[1],size);  */

    P   =   gsl_spline_eval(spline,log(x),acc); 
    result  =   exp(P)*f(gamma)*gamma;
    return(result);
}
```

When I include the lines

```cpp
 /* double table[2][MAXPOINTS];
    size = read_table(table[0],table[1]);   
    gsl_interp_accel *acc      =      gsl_interp_accel_alloc ();
        gsl_spline *spline    =      gsl_spline_alloc (gsl_interp_interp, 5401);        
    gsl_spline_init(spline,table[0],table[1],size);  */
```

in the function `sync_kern()` and not in `main()` **then it works**: I get the right value of  `GSL_FN_EVAL(&F,nu)` **but it takes of course too much time...**

I hope my message wasn't too long...I am not a great expert of c++ and I've look all the aspects of the problem and I still don't understand where it comes from...Does someone have any idea?
Please don't hesitate do ask me if you need any further informations.
Thanks a lot for your help!

Maybe I should precise that I got my code from my supervisor's code. Which is slightly different:

```cpp
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    struct func_params params;
    size_t size;
    int i;
    /* initializing parameters */
    initialize(argc, argv, &params);

    /* Interpolation of  Synchrotronfunction F(x) */

        double table[2][MAXPOINTS];
        size = read_table(table[0],table[1]);       /*Tabelle fuer Interpolation einlesen aus create_table.c*/
        params.acc = gsl_interp_accel_alloc();
        params.spline = gsl_spline_alloc(gsl_interp_linear, size);
        gsl_spline_init(params.spline,table[0],table[1],size);
...
return (0);
}   


double
sync_kern(double gamma, void *params)
{
    struct func_params *part= (struct func_params *)params;
    double result;
    double P,nu_c,x;
    gamma = exp(gamma);
    nu_c    =   part->nu_0*sq(gamma);
    x   =   part->nu_s/nu_c;
    P   =   gsl_spline_eval(part->spline,log(x),part->acc); /*Aus Interpolation: Pointer auf spline */

    result  =   exp(P)*f(gamma)*gamma;
    return(result);
}
```

Where *spline* and *acc* are defined in a file.h:

```cpp
struct func_params
    {   
    gsl_spline *spline;
    gsl_interp_accel *acc;
    ...
    }
void initialize(int argc, char *argv[], void *params)
{
struct func_params *part= (struct func_params *)params; 
/* Default values for parameters: */
    part->gmin=1.0e7/M_E_EV;
    part->gamma=1.0e10/M_E_EV;
    part->gmax=2.0e18/M_E_EV;   /*Integrationgrenzen fuer gamma festlegen*/
    part->nu=1e-9/H_EV; 
...
}
```

I defined *spline* and *acc* in my function `sync_kern()` and him in a structure. Does someone has an idea where the error can come from?

Answer (score 0):

> The function read_table() gives the arrays 'x[]' and 'y[]' used for
>   the interpolation

```
double table[2][MAXPOINTS];
size = read_table(table[0],table[1]);
```

You define an array of doubles, but don't initialize it. It contains random values. So likely it runs with absurd results.

You pass two values to read_table(). If you want the function to change them, the definition of this function should be

```
size_t read_table(double& val1, double& val2);
```

Review your code. There are some vars without declaration (nu_0, nuc, acc)

### EDIT

After you edited the question, I see how read_table() is defined. It uses two pointers. You have an only array, two dimensions, fixed size. Because of this fixed size, it's OK to pass the array by using two pointers, `table[0]` and `table[1]`.

double `table[2][N]` is same as `double** table`. So passing table[1] is passing a pointer to an array[N].

The gsl error is due to this code at gsl:interp.c
https://github.com/ampl/gsl/blob/master/interpolation/interp.c

```
  if (x < interp->xmin || x > interp->xmax)
    {
      GSL_ERROR_VAL("interpolation error", GSL_EDOM, GSL_NAN);
    }
```

It seems you are trying an interpolation out of limits (called "extrapolation")

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I've printed different values of table[][] in my function main and I get well the expected values contained in my function read_table() . nu_0, nuc and acc are well declared in my code, I just forgot to copy the corresponding line of their declarations.

Comment: I thought that an array is a pointer in C++, then if if I want table[0] and table[1] to be changed
`read_table(table[0],table[1])`

should be correct right?

Comment: Yes, an array declared as "sometype myArray[];" is the same as "sometype* myArray;" The matter is how you declare in a function the parameters to pass the whole array or just some values; and if that function allows changing the parameters or just change a copy of them.

Comment: Okay....but then what should I write...?

`read_table(&table[0],&table[1])`

I don't understand...

Comment: Actually I also thought the same at the beginning, but as I said, when I remove the following lines
   `double table[2][MAXPOINTS];`
    size = read_table(table[0],table[1]);   
    gsl_interp_accel *acc      =      gsl_interp_accel_alloc ();
        gsl_spline *spline    =      gsl_spline_alloc (gsl_interp_interp, 5401);        
    gsl_spline_init(spline,table[0],table[1],size);
  `
from my function `main()` and put them in the function `sync_kern()` it works but it's too slow